# Derivative of a vector x wrt itself

Tags: matrix-calculus

I am attempting to better understand matrix calculus. Given a vector $x$, I understand that:
$\frac{\mathrm{d} x^t}{\mathrm{d} x}= I$ but struggle to think about $\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} x}$. [This](https://www.matrixcalculus.org/) website says it is also the identity matrix, but I struggle to understand why. Would taking the derivative of a column vector wrt a column vector produce a tensor? Any intuition is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the definition for vector-on-vector differentiation used on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector), then the derivative of a column vector with respect to another column vector is indeed a matrix. To provide some intuition, consider $x'=f(x)$ as defining a coordinate transformation. (That is, $x_1'=f_1(x), x_2'=f_2(x)$, etc.) Then $dx'/dx$
is just the Jacobian matrix for this transformation, and it shouldn't be surprising that the  identity transformation $f(x)=x$ has the identity matrix as its Jacobian.

Another route is to think in terms of linearization: If $y=f(x)$, then $$f(x+\epsilon h)=f(x)+ϵf′(x)h+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)=y+ϵ (dy/dx) h+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$
So the linearization of $f(x)$ only works if $(dy/dx)h$ is another column vector, i.e., $dy/dx$ is a matrix. (If you want a headache, try thinking about the $\epsilon^2$ terms!)

Comment: So we can. simply say $\frac{\mathrm{d} x^t}{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} x}$

Comment: This does seem to be the case, but it may depend on the exact conventions used. As a point of support, though, Gentle's text on Matrix Algebra takes $\partial f/\partial x=\partial f/\partial x^t$ as true by convention ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pbz3D7Tg5eoC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA152#v=onepage&q&f=false)). But in Gentle's case one then has between $\partial f/\partial x^t=(\partial f/\partial x)^t =(\partial f^t/\partial x)^t$, so the situation is a bit subtle.